Traveling abroad, changing identifying gender and coming back to the Czech republic
I'm nonbinary and from the Czech republic, but because of that, I can't legally put "O" or "X" on my id for gender because it's not recognized. I'm planning on "moving" to Germany, where such a thing is possible. When I'm there, I am most likely going to change my id gender for "X" or whatever they offer as a third option the second I get there. My question is, since I'll still TECHNICALLY be a Czech resident, once i come back here, will it have to be changed back to what it says now?

Good luck, but I suspect you would still be a Czech resident but that Czechia would not recognise your gender change.

The only way this would work is, you move to Germany, you live long enough (5+ years) and fulfill the naturalization requirements, become a German citizen, and then obtain German identification documents.

Please state clearly if you are a citizen of  the Czech republic, since another EU country cannot change what is contained in your national ID or Passport.

@Dr.Snoopy And I'm not sure even that would be enough. OP would also have to renounce their Czech citizenship, move back to Czechia as a German national at that point, and then presumably obtain Czech permanent residence or citizenship again. And I don't think anyone knows what would happen at that point, but I suspect there's a decent probability that their original official Czech gender would spring back into life, because Germany is likely not going to issue a new birth certificate.

The real/core question here, is how an EU country reacts when a EU citizen (with a O/X gender in their ID/Passport) takes up residence in a EU Country that does not reconize an O/X gender. A EU citizen is only required to have an ID or Passwort (not a birth certificate).

@TooTea I think Germany may in fact issue a new birth certificate. The law definitely provides for that for people born in Germany and there are also special procedures for people born abroad.

I am not quite sure I understand what you plan to do or what kind of document you hope to get from Germany and why. If you move there, you would not be a Czech resident, technically or otherwise, but that doesn't really matter. German law on “self-determination” does explicitly apply to foreign residents but practical consequences are limited to the documents issued in Germany.
You will get some documents from the German authorities (registration confirmation, maybe even a residence permit, even though they stopped routinely issuing those to EU citizens many years ago) that should therefore state your preferred gender but your country of origin will still be responsible for your ID documents.
Germany actually requires you to have a valid Czech passport or national identity card to enter and stay. Germany will not issue any ID card for you and won't touch the one you got. And when your documents expire, you still wouldn't get a German ID card, instead  you will be required to renew them through the Czech consulate. So as far as the Czech authorities are concerned, your gender will still be the same and there is nothing to “change back”.

It is the Free Movement Directive 2004/38/EC (which must be implemented into national law) that requires EU citizens to have a valid passport or national identity card.

@MarkJohnson That's inaccurate and I think I already explained that somewhere. What the directive does is forbid states from refusing to extend freedom of movement rights to EU citizens as long as they have a valid national ID card or passport. It does not force countries to impose a German-style mandatory ID law nor create any obligation for EU citizens.

'as long as they have a valid national ID card or passport' therfore you aggree with my previous comment. Kindy explain what the you consider to be inaccurate. Germany does not issue an ID to non-German nationals.

@MarkJohnson No, I do not and it does not follow from what I just wrote. I just explained why: The directive provides that having a national ID or passport is enough, not that it is necessary. The directive imposes requirements on states, not on EU citizens. In practice, of course, holding an ID document is advisable regardless and the distinction is mostly theoretical but you brought it up for some reason…

(-1) 'No, I do not' you stated that it is German law (in your answer), but it is actually EU law based on the Free Movement Directive 2004/38/EC (which you have confirmed in two different comments). And since Germany only issues ID to their own nationals, your comment 'to impose a German-style mandatory ID law' is also moot.

@MarkJohnson Uh? EU law allows it and German law demands it. What's hard to grasp about that? I never said anything else, you are free to disagree but stop putting words in my mouth! It's also absurd to pretend it's based on that directive when it was the case long before 2004 and applies equally to German citizens, EU citizens and third-country nationals.

My interpretation is still that EU law doesn't require a German-style mandatory ID law. That's not moot, that's the whole point of my comment. Incidentally, you want to debate this highly theoretical issue and I am indulging you but what exactly is wrong about my answer? German law requires EU citizens to hold a national ID card or passport, does it not? Whether it is required by EU law or not, that's still a completely accurate statement!
